# How to get values from a Column in pandas if another column in same dataframe matches a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, multiple-columns

```
     Tax_Amount Rate    SGST    CGST    IGST    TDS Tax_Term

0   5697.0  9.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN CGST
1   954.0   9.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN TDS
2   1305.0  9.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN CGST
3   2724.0  9.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN SGST
4   18000.0 9.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN IGST
```

i Have a Dataframe as above, I want to have the Tax_Amount in all respective column if it matches the Colum Tax_Term.
Expected Output:-

```
    Tax_Amount  Rate    SGST    CGST    IGST    TDS Tax_Term
0   5697.0  9.0 NaN 5697.0  NaN NaN CGST
1   954.0   9.0 NaN 954.0   NaN 954.0   TDS
2   1305.0  9.0 NaN 1305.0  NaN NaN CGST
3   2724.0  9.0 2724.0  NaN NaN NaN SGST
4   18000.0 9.0 NaN NaN 18000.0 NaN IGST
```

I tried doing the same with below code however i didn't get the desired result.

```
final_df['SGST'] = final_df.query('Tax_Term == SGST')['Tax_Amount']
final_df['CGST'] = final_df.query('Tax_Term == CGST')['Tax_Amount']
final_df['IGST'] = final_df.query('Tax_Term == IGST')['Tax_Amount']
final_df['TDS'] = final_df.query('Tax_Term == TDS')['Tax_Amount']
```

any help will be appretiated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there are few values in the `Tax_Term` column, you can simply use a series of assignments using `.loc`:

```
final_df.loc[final_df['Tax_Term'] == 'CGST','CGST'] =final_df['Tax_Ammount']
final_df.loc[final_df['Tax_Term'] == 'TDS', 'TDS'] = final_df['Tax_Ammount']
final_df.loc[final_df['Tax_Term'] == 'SGST', 'SGST'] = final_df['Tax_Ammount']
final_df.loc[final_df['Tax_Term'] == 'IGST', 'IGST'] = final_df['Tax_Ammount']
```

Or, you can create a loop that iterates over unique values in `Tax_term`:

```
for term in final_df.Tax_Term.unique():
    final_df.loc[final_df['Tax_Term'] == term,
                 term] = final_df['Tax_Ammount']
```